# Ioinic + phonegap push - notification icon does not show

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have tried this several times now by using code mentioned in [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/608)

The icon generated using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) utility
[image]

Push notification init code

```
 var push = PushNotification.init({
          android: {
            senderID: "gcm_id",
            icon: "ic_notification",
            iconColor: "black"
          }
        });
```

The folders in `platform/android/res`, they all contain generated `ic_notification.png`

[image]

But my notification still does not show the icon. It shows blank white square.

[image]

`Cordova version 6.0.`
`Ionic version 1.7.14`
`android-minSdkVersion: 16`
`android-targetSdkVersion: 23`

Has anyone able to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing wrong in above setup. The notification payload needed to have correct icon name.

```
const gcmMessage = new gcm.Message({
   priority: 'high',
   notification: {
     title: 'Title',
     icon: 'ic_notification',
     body: 'test'
   }
});
```